# How do I select a node based on one of its edges in igraph?

Tags: r, igraph

If I had a code like the following:

```
library(igraph)

g <- erdos.renyi.game(20, 50 , type = "gnm" , directed = F , loops = F) %>%
  set_vertex_attr("a", value = 0) %>%
  set_vertex_attr("aa", value = 0) %>%
  set_edge_attr("b", value = 0) %>%
  set_vertex_attr("z", value = 0) 

V(g)$aa <- sample(c(0, .25, .5, .75, 1), vcount(g), replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.3, 0.15, 0.3, 0.15, 0.1))

V(g)$a[V(g)$aa <= V(g)$z & V(g)$a == 0] <- 1

V(g)$z <- sapply(V(g), function(x) { 
    NeighborList = neighbors(g, x) ; 
    ifelse(length(NeighborList) > 0, 
    length(NeighborList[NeighborList$a == 1])/length(NeighborList),0) } )

sum <- sum(head_of(g,E(g))$a==0 & tail_of(g,E(g))$a==0)

E(g)$b[head_of(g,E(g))$a==0 & tail_of(g,E(g))$a==0] <- sample(rep(0:1, c(sum-1, 1)), sum)

g <- delete_edges(g, E(g)[E(g)$b == 1])
```

In which it deletes a single edge, how can I change the attributes of the nodes that just lost a connection? So if nodes 1 and 5 were the ones that lost the edge between them, how can I change their attribute values for a without specifying 1 and 5 (so that it can be used regardless of what edge was removed)

Comment: Would the edge be deleted by some random process, so you'd need to detect after the fact which edge had been deleted, or would you be deciding which edge is deleted before the deletion?

Comment: The edge is deleted by a random process but it's a 2 part process so, an edge is randomly decided to be deleted first.

Comment: I changed the code so that it actually depicts the deletion process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to put together a data frame listing connected nodes and then check which one is absent from the updated graph. I've done this with mix of `igraph`, base R and `tidyverse` functions, but there may be a better way. The code below can be packaged up into a function that takes an igraph object, deletes an edge and returns the updated igraph object and the names of the nodes whose edge was deleted.

First, let's recreate your graph but we'll set a seed for reproducibility:

```
set.seed(2)
g <- erdos.renyi.game(20, 50 , type = "gnm" , directed = F , loops = F) %>%
  set_vertex_attr("a", value = 0) %>%
  set_vertex_attr("aa", value = 0) %>%
  set_edge_attr("b", value = 0) %>%
  set_vertex_attr("z", value = 0) 

V(g)$aa <- sample(c(0, .25, .5, .75, 1), vcount(g), replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.3, 0.15, 0.3, 0.15, 0.1))

V(g)$a[V(g)$aa <= V(g)$z & V(g)$a == 0] <- 1

V(g)$z <- sapply(V(g), function(x) { 
  NeighborList = neighbors(g, x) ; 
  ifelse(length(NeighborList) > 0, 
         length(NeighborList[NeighborList$a == 1])/length(NeighborList),0) } )

sum <- sum(head_of(g,E(g))$a==0 & tail_of(g,E(g))$a==0)

E(g)$b[head_of(g,E(g))$a==0 & tail_of(g,E(g))$a==0] <- sample(rep(0:1, c(sum-1, 1)), sum)
```

Now to detect which edge was removed:

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Create a data frame listing which nodes of `g` are currently connected:

```
adj = as.data.frame(get.edgelist(g)) %>% mutate(adj_before=1)

adj
```

> ```
>    V1 V2 adj_before
> 1   1  3          1
> 2   1  4          1
> 3   4  5          1
> ...
> 13  5 10          1
> 14  9 10          1
> 15  1 11          1
> ...
> 48  7 20          1
> 49  9 20          1
> 50 10 20          1
> ```

Now we'll delete an edge in the manner you specified.

```
g <- delete_edges(g, E(g)[E(g)$b == 1])
```

Now we can create a data frame listing which nodes are connected in the updated graph `g` and `left_join` it to the existing `adj` data frame. There will be an `NA` in the row for the pair of nodes whose edge has been deleted.

```
adj = adj %>% 
  left_join(as.data.frame(get.edgelist(g)) %>% 
              mutate(adj_after=1))

adj
```

> ```
>    V1 V2 adj_before adj_after
> 1   1  3          1         1
> 2   1  4          1         1
> 3   4  5          1         1
> ...
> 13  5 10          1         1
> 14  9 10          1        NA
> 15  1 11          1         1
> ...
> 48  7 20          1         1
> 49  9 20          1         1
> 50 10 20          1         1
> ```

To get a vector listing the two nodes whose edge has been deleted, you just need to select the row where `adj_after` is `NA`:

```
Vs = unlist(adj[which(is.na(adj$adj_after)), c("V1","V2")])

Vs
```

> ```
> V1 V2 
>  9 10
> ```

Now, let's say you want to change attribute `a` for the nodes whose edge has just been deleted:

```
# Current attribute `a` values:
V(g)$a
```

> ```
> [1] 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
> ```

```
V(g)$a[Vs] = 3

V(g)$a
```

> ```
> [1] 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 3 3 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
> ```

Comment: How would I edit the attributes of the nodes after this automatically?

Comment: My knowledge of igraph is limited. If you provide code showing how to edit the attributes you want to change, I can show you how to apply that code in the context of my answer.

Comment: Usually I employ code such as this:   V(g)$a["prerequisite"] <- 3, where prerequisite is some value that restricts the nodes for which the attribute value for "a" is changed.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what to do with that. We know that nodes 9 and 10 are the ones whose attributes we want to change, and I've now saved those values in the vector `Vs`. Can you provide more context? There's no "prerequisite" attribute in your example code. You just need to use `Vs` to access the nodes whose edge has been deleted and then change the attributes of those nodes.

Comment: So if there is someway that you can convert the values for V1 and V2 to another list such as one named xyz (xyz <- c("V1", "V2") didn't work). I can change the value by running a command such as: V(g)$a[xyz] <- 3 which will successfully modify the attribute values for nodes V1 and V2.

Comment: See the update to my answer and let me know if that's what you were trying to do.